# How do you tether using ubuntu phone, under windows?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, windows-10, tethering, adb

I know how to do this in Ubuntu, using `adb`, but right now, I have stupid windows 10.

How can I tether using my ubuntu phone (nexus 4) in windows 10?

Comment: Have you tried the hotspot option?

Comment: @pomsky Ubuntu Phone has a hotspot option?

Comment: Yep! Since OTA-6 if I remember correctly.